# Needing TOP group item from SQL query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by

I'm sure this is a simple query but it's had me stumped for a while. I need to join two tables and return only a specific record for each grouping.

Here are the tables I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileData](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FinDataID] [int] NULL,
    [PharmacyID] [int] NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [FileExtension] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedByID] [int] NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedByID] [int] NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinData](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PharmacyID] [int] NULL,
    [PeriodStart] [date] NULL,
    [PeriodEnd] [date] NULL,
    [SalesTotal] [money] NULL,
    [SalesDisp] [money] NULL,
    [SalesRetail] [money] NULL,
    [GPTotal] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [GPRetail] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [GPDisp] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [Advertising] [money] NULL,
    [Rent] [money] NULL,
    [GrossWages] [money] NULL,
    [Depreciation] [money] NULL,
    [InterestExp] [money] NULL,
    [AllOtherExp] [money] NULL,
    [OwnerHours] [money] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedByID] [int] NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedById] [int] NULL
```

These tables contained the following sample data:

```
FileData:
ID   FinDataID  PharmacyID yadayada
6    13         1
7    13         1
8    13         1
9    13         1
10   15         2
12   13         1
13   13         1

FinData: (where Pharmacy = 1)
ID  PharmacyID  PeriodStart
1   1           2012-07-01
13  1           2011-07-01
```

Here is a sample query that I was using originally:

```
SELECT
 FD.ID, FinData.ID AS FinDataID, FD.PharmacyID, FinData.PeriodStart, FinData.PeriodEnd, FileName, FileExtension, ISNULL(DATA,0) AS Data, FD.CreateDate, FD.CreatedByID, FD.UpdateDate, FD.UpdatedById
FROM FinData
LEFT JOIN FileData FD ON FD.FinDataID = FinData.ID
WHERE FinData.PharmacyID = @PharmacyID
ORDER BY PeriodStart desc, ID DESC
```

which returned the following data:

```
ID   FinDataID   PharmacyID   PeriodStart   yadayadayada
NULL 1           NULL         2012-07-01   
13   13          1            2011-07-01
12   13          1            2011-07-01
9    13          1            2011-07-01
8    13          1            2011-07-01
7    13          1            2011-07-01
6    13          1            2011-07-01
```

Basically I'm needing the top record for each FinDataID in that result... I know I'm close but haven't found the solution yet!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a max() function?

Comment: Sample input data and expected result would help understand what you're looking for. I don't think the data output of the wrong query helps.

Comment: Sorry, to answer questions, this is on SQL Server 2008. Also, Mostacho, you're right I should have included sample data but didn't because I thought my existing query could be used as a subquery... I'll put sample data in now for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH Data as
(
  SELECT
     FD.ID, FinData.ID AS FinDataID, FD.PharmacyID, FinData.PeriodStart, FinData.PeriodEnd, FileName, FileExtension, ISNULL(DATA,0) AS Data, FD.CreateDate, FD.CreatedByID, FD.UpdateDate, FD.UpdatedById
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [FinDataID]
                      ORDER BY [PeriodStart] DESC, [ID] DESC) as [Rank]
  FROM FinData
  LEFT JOIN FileData FD ON FD.FinDataID = FinData.ID
  WHERE FinData.PharmacyID = @PharmacyID
)
SELECT *
FROM [Data]
WHERE [Rank] = 1
```

Note the result set will also include the [Rank] column, so filter that guy out and you're good to go.

Comment: Seems more complicated than necessary.  Plus, OP did not specify his rdmbs so there is an element of doubt as to whether it will support this syntax.

Comment: Great! Never thought I'd be thanking J Lo for anything but thanks! I had to identify the [ID] column in the ORDER BY but other than that it's perfect!